# Generate a unique combination from an index within the number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm writing a program which will use a genetic algorithm optimize neural networks to play tic-tac-toe (That's not related), and I've come across the following problem:

I'm looping through every permutation of a tic-tac-toe game ($3^9$ or 362880) and from that number, I want to generate one of those $3^9$ combinations. I think it might be possible using bases, however, ideally (and reasonably) the 362880th permutation should be:

```
2 | 2 | 2
---------
2 | 2 | 2
---------
2 | 2 | 2
```

However, 362880 in base 3 isn't even 9 digits long (it's 12: `200102210000`).

Anyway, the questions is: **Given a number n, between $1$ and $3^9$ inclusive, is it possible, and if so, how, to generate a unique set of length $9$ with values of either $0$, $1$ or $2$ (i.e. base 3)**

Any help is much appreciated,

Brendan

Comment: $3^9=19683$. What you want to do is take a number in $\{0,1,2\dots 19682=3^9-1\}$ and write it in base $3$, then fill the squares in order (order the spaces any way you like).

Comment: @CarryonSmiling I will try this, and report back.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling It worked! Thanks, if you want to, you can submit an answer, so I can mark it as correct. Regardless, thank you! I can't believe I was that dumb :p

Comment: Great, gald it helped (don't worry, that happens to me all the time also when I am coding) =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3^9$ is actually $19683$ which is $1000000000$ in base $9$.

The numbers in the range $0,3^9-1$ all have an expression of length $9$ in base $3$.

What you want to do is label the spots in the tick tack toe as follows:

```
    9 | 8 | 7
    ---------
    6 | 5 | 4
    ---------
    3 | 2 | 1
```

And then, assign to every number in the range $0,3^n-1$ a tick tack toe board depending on its base $3$ expression.

So for example $1234$ is $001200201$ in base $3$. So we assing the following board to $1234$:

```
    0 | 0 | 1
    ---------
    2 | 0 | 0
    ---------
    2 | 0 | 1
```